# combined different objects contains plots and data frames (tables) and paragraphs (markdowns) in to single html report

Tags: python, html, reporting

I want to generate a single report that integrates different objects as my analysis inlcudes plots (matplotlib, seaborn and bokeh) and pandas data frames (tables) and paragraphs (markdowns) into an HTML report in python

Comment: Preferably interactive plots

Comment: show your research efforts/ what you tried. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'s how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jupyter or Zeppelin notebooks. They provide all of the functionality you described and can export to PDF. Reports can even be run/emailed on a predetermined schedule.